# Optimising Haskell data reading from file

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement Kosaraju's graph algorithm, on a [3.5m line file](http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/algo1/programming_prob/SCC.zip) where each row is two (space separated) Ints representing a graph edge.  To start I need to create a summary data structure that has the node and lists of its incoming and outgoing edges.  The code below achieves that, but takes over a minute, whereas I can see from posts on the MOOC forum that people using other languages are completing in <<10s.  (`getLines` is taking 10s compared to under 1s in benchmarks I read about.)

I'm new to Haskell and have implemented an accumulation method using `foldl'` (the `'` was a breakthrough in making it terminate at all), but it feels rather imperative in style, and I'm hoping that that's the reason why it is running slow.  Moreover, I'm currently planning to use a similar pattern to conduct the depth-first-search, and I fear it will all just become too slow.

I have found this [presentation](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/downloads/slides-faster_haskell-10_aug_2007.pdf) and [blog](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.be/2014/01/optimising-haskell-for-tight-inner-loop.html) that talk about these sort of issues but at too expert a level.

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.List as L

type NodeName = Int
type Edges = [NodeName]
type Explored = Bool

data Node = Node Explored (Edges, Edges) deriving (Show)

type Graph1 = Map NodeName Node

getLines :: FilePath -> IO [[Int]]
getLines = liftM (fmap (fmap read . words) . lines) . readFile

getLines' :: FilePath -> IO [(Int,Int)]
getLines' = liftM (fmap (tuplify2 . fmap read . words) . lines) . readFile

tuplify2 :: [a] -> (a,a)
tuplify2 [x,y] = (x,y)

main = do
    list <- getLines "testdata.txt"  -- [String]
    --list <- getLines "SCC.txt"  -- [String]   
    let
        list' = createGraph list
    return list'

createGraph :: [[Int]] -> Graph1
createGraph xs = L.foldl' build Map.empty xs
    where
        build :: Graph1-> [Int] -> Graph1
        build = \acc (x:y:_) ->
            let tmpAcc = case Map.lookup x acc of
                Nothing -> Map.insert x (Node False ([y],[])) acc
                Just a -> Map.adjust (\(Node _ (fwd, bck)) -> (Node False ((y:fwd), bck))) x acc
            in case Map.lookup y tmpAcc of
                Nothing -> Map.insert y (Node False ([],[x])) tmpAcc
                Just a -> Map.adjust (\(Node _ (fwd, bck)) -> (Node False (fwd, (x:bck)))) y tmpAcc
```

Comment: You should consider using an array. Also, a list of exactly two elements shoud immediately smell fishy.

Comment: Will look at Arrays.  The two element list comes straight from the source file and represents an edge.

Comment: There are other data structures beside the list. If you have exactly two of anything, list is not the first choice.

Comment: Is the range of the node indices known beforehand?

Comment: Yes, I could read off the first number in each line if needed.  The list is sorted, there are many edges from each node, and the node numbers run from 1 to 800k with some gaps

Comment: @n.m. the list is just the output of words - converting to e.g. a tuple would just add overhead?

Comment: You don't have to use `words` in the first place.

Comment: Could you use `Data.IntMap` instead of `Data.Map`?

Comment: Don't guess - profile.

Comment: @DonStewart When I read this question, I thought of you.

Comment: After using `:set +s` I found that in the Byststring code below, the stage of turning the list into tuples increased the total read time from under 4 seconds to around 12. I don;t know yet whether I would win that time back in later parts of the algorithm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Using maps:

- Use `IntMap` or `HashMap` when possible. Both are significantly faster for `Int` keys than `Map`. `HashMap` is usually faster than `IntMap` but uses more RAM and has a less rich library.
- Don't do unnecessary lookups. The `containers` package has a large number of specialized functions. With [`alter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-IntMap-Strict.html#g:7) the number of lookups can be halved compared to the `createGraph` implementation in the question.

Example for `createGraph`:

```
import Data.List (foldl')
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM

type NodeName = Int
type Edges = [NodeName]
type Explored = Bool

data Node = Node Explored Edges Edges deriving (Eq, Show)
type Graph1 = IM.IntMap Node

createGraph :: [(Int, Int)] -> Graph1
createGraph xs = foldl' build IM.empty xs
    where
        addFwd y (Just (Node _ f b)) = Just (Node False (y:f) b)
        addFwd y _                   = Just (Node False [y] [])
        addBwd x (Just (Node _ f b)) = Just (Node False f (x:b))
        addBwd x _                   = Just (Node False [] [x])

        build :: Graph1 -> (Int, Int) -> Graph1
        build acc (x, y) = IM.alter (addBwd x) y $ IM.alter (addFwd y) x acc
```

#### Using [vectors:](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.11.0/docs/Data-Vector.html)

- Consider the efficient construction functions (the accumulators, unfolds, `generate`, `iterate`, `constructN`, etc.). These may use mutation behind the scenes but are considerably more convenient to use than actual mutable vectors.
- In the more general case, use the laziness of boxed vectors to enable self-reference when constructing a vector.
- Use unboxed vectors when possible.
- Use unsafe functions when you're absolutely sure about the bounds.
- Only use mutable vectors when there aren't pure alternatives. In that case, prefer the ST monad to IO. Also, avoid creating [many mutable heap objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462004/code-becomes-slower-as-more-boxed-arrays-are-allocated/) (i. e. prefer mutable vectors to immutable vectors of mutable references).

Example for `createGraph`:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

type NodeName = Int
type Edges = [NodeName]
type Explored = Bool

data Node = Node Explored Edges Edges deriving (Eq, Show)
type Graph1 = V.Vector Node

createGraph :: Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> Graph1
createGraph maxIndex edges = graph'' where
    graph    = V.replicate maxIndex (Node False [] [])
    graph'   = V.accum (\(Node e f b) x -> Node e (x:f) b) graph  edges
    graph''  = V.accum (\(Node e f b) x -> Node e f (x:b)) graph' (map (\(a, b) -> (b, a)) edges)
```

Note that if there are gaps in the range of the node indices, then it'd be wise to either

1. Contiguously relabel the indices before doing anything else.
2. Introduce an empty constructor to `Node` to signify a missing index.

#### Faster I/O:

- Use the IO functions from `Data.Text` or `Data.ByteString`. In both cases there are also efficient functions for breaking input into lines or words.

Example:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import System.IO

getLines :: FilePath -> IO [(Int, Int)]
getLines path = do
    lines <- (map BS.words . BS.lines) `fmap` BS.readFile path
    let pairs = (map . map) (maybe (error "can't read Int") fst . BS.readInt) lines
    return [(a, b) | [a, b] <- pairs]
```

#### Benchmarking:

Always do it, unlike me in this answer. Use [`criterion`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).

Comment: This is awesome and I will work through it progressively.  Learning Criterion is probably too much in the short run, but I tried your IntMap solution and it reduced runtime from 113s to 100s (and your code also includes the tuplify, which adds some time relative to my benchmark).  Moe to follow

Comment: @SimonH1000 Criterion is actually really easy. The simplest uses of it are importing [`Criterion.Main`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-0.8.1.0/docs/Criterion-Main.html) then using `defaultMain`, `bench`, and whichever of the set `nf`, `whnf`, `nfIO`, or `whnfIO` you need.

Comment: Thirding `criterion`; even if you just have a simple test that runs your `createGraph` on some pre-defined input, being able to see the distribution of runs, and having accurate measurements (as opposed to using `time`) will save you a ton of time and headaches. And once you've got your first test set up, it's really easy to add other bits of your program in there to make sure you have an accurate view of your code's performance.

Comment: I've added some Criterion code in my answer (but not the change to main).  I get a bunch of numbers out but can't find a simple run time

Answer (score 4):

Based pretty much on András' suggestions, I've reduced a 113 second task down to 24 (measured by stopwatch as I can't quite get Criterion to do anything yet) (and then down to 10 by compiling -O2)!!!  I've attended some courses this last year that talked about the challenge of optimising for large datasets but this was the first time I faced a question that actually involved one, and it was as non-trivial as my instructors' suggested.  This is what I have now:

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import Data.List (foldl')
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

type NodeName = Int
type Edges = [NodeName]
type Explored = Bool

data Node = Node Explored Edges Edges deriving (Eq, Show)
type Graph1 = IM.IntMap Node

-- DFS uses a stack to store next points to explore, a list can do this
type Stack = [(NodeName, NodeName)]

getBytes :: FilePath -> IO [(Int, Int)]
getBytes path = do
    lines <- (map BS.words . BS.lines) `fmap` BS.readFile path
    let
        pairs = (map . map) (maybe (error "Can't read integers") fst . BS.readInt) lines
    return [(a,b) | [a,b] <- pairs]

main = do
    --list <- getLines' "testdata.txt"  -- [String]
    list <- getBytes "SCC.txt"  -- [String] 
    let list' = createGraph' list
    putStrLn $ show $ list' IM.! 66
    -- return list'


bmark = defaultMain [
    bgroup "1" [
        bench "Sim test" $ whnf bmark' "SCC.txt"
        ]
    ]

bmark' :: FilePath -> IO ()
bmark' path = do
    list <- getLines path
    let
        list' = createGraph list
    putStrLn $ show $ list' IM.! 2


createGraph' :: [(Int, Int)] -> Graph1
createGraph' xs = foldl' build IM.empty xs
    where
        addFwd y (Just (Node _ f b)) = Just (Node False (y:f) b)
        addFwd y _                   = Just (Node False [y] [])
        addBwd x (Just (Node _ f b)) = Just (Node False f (x:b))
        addBwd x _                   = Just (Node False [] [x])

        build :: Graph1 -> (Int, Int) -> Graph1
        build acc (x, y) = IM.alter (addBwd x) y $ IM.alter (addFwd y) x acc
```

And now on with the rest of the exercise....

Comment: Good job! By the way, I looked at your SCC.txt, and it actually has a contiguous range of nodes, with only the node "0" missing. So I could use pretty much the same `vector` code that I delineated. [Here's a gist for it](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/582808b6b5cc67bc36a2). Also, it runs in **4,7 secs** on my computer.

Comment: Also, did you compile with optimizations (-O2, possibly also -fllvm)? I also ran the code you just posted here and it finished in 6,3 secs for me (or maybe you have a slower computer... I have Core i7 3770 CPU).

Comment: WOW - I was a simple Prelude user until 5 mins ago - now down to 10s after first compiling with `ghc -O2 <filename>`

Comment: @AndrásKovács Regrettably there is no node 37 for example, so Vector's are out, without a renumbering at least

Comment: You can store absent node as node without inbound and outbound edges. You can share the empty node between all the missing nodes, such that they only cost you the space for a pointer in the vector.

Comment: @SimonH1000: node 37 is there in the edges as a second entry. I still think the nodes are complete.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected.  Just need to decide whether Vector will stand me in good stead for rest of the exercise (think it will) and then reimplement the code - this is really a good learning exercise which is why so many people seem to be following it

Comment: @AndrásKovács I tried to implement vector myself (using `foldl'`) before looking at your gist. I blew up my memory and had to hard reboot!  Yours ran in 8s. I am so impressed, but am left wondering whether there is documentation to help make these sort of design decisions.

Answer (score 3):

*This is not really an answer, I would rather comment András Kovács post, if I add those 50 points...*

I have implemented the loading of the graph in both IntMap and MVector, in a attempt to benchmark mutability vs. immutability.

Both program use Attoparsec for the parsing. There is surely more economic way to do it, but Attoparsec is relatively fast compared to its high abstraction level (the parser can stand in one line). The guideline is to avoid `String` and `read`. `read` is partial and slow, `[Char]` is slow and not memory efficient, unless properly fused.

As András Kovács noted, IntMap is better than Map for Int keys. My code provides another example of `alter` usage. If the node identifier mapping is dense, you may also want to use Vector and Array. They allow O(1) indexing by the identifier.

The mutable version handle on demand the exponential growth of the MVector. This avoid to precise an upper bound on node identifiers, but introduce more complexity (the reference on the vector may change).

I benchmarked with a file of 5M edges with identifiers in the range [0..2^16]. The MVector version is ~2x faster than the IntMap code (12s vs 25s on my computer).

The code is [here [Gist]](https://gist.github.com/Piezoid/da254cc0e812dba501f4).

I will edit when more profiling is done on my side.

Comment: There is something wrong with my parser : it accumulate lots of bytestring. I tried to make it more strict, but it still the same.