# Haskell: Optimising Graph processing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, haskell, optimization

This is a follow up to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344440/optimising-haskell-data-processing-part-ii), with code now based on [Structuring Depth-First Search Algorithms in Haskell to do depth first search](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/2252048_Structuring_Depth-First_Search_Algorithms_in_Haskell/file/50463523c7a64b12d4.pdf), by King and Launchbury in the 1990s.  That paper suggests a generate and prune strategy, but uses a mutable array with a State Monad (with some grammar that I suspect has since been deprecated). The authors hint that a set could be used for remembering nodes visited, as the cost of an additional O(log n).  I tried to implement with a set (we have better machines now than they did in the 1990s!), to use modern State Monad syntax, and to use Vectors rather than arrays (as I read that that is normally better).

As before, my code runs on small data sets, but fails to return on the 5m edge graph I need to analyse, and I'm looking for **hints only** as to the weakness operating at scale.  What I do know is that the code operates comfortably within memory, so that is not the problem, but have I inadvertently slipped to O(n2)?  (By contrast, the official implementation of this paper in the Data.Graph library (which I have lately also borrowed some code from) uses a mutable Array but fails on the big data set with a ... Stack Overflow!!!)

So now I have a Vector data store with IntSet State that does not complete and an Array with ST Monad Array 'official' one that crashes! Haskell should be able to do better than this?

```
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import qualified Data.IntSet as IS
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Control.Monad.State

type Vertex   = Int
type Table a  = Vector a
type Graph    = Table [Vertex]
type Edge     = (Vertex, Vertex)
data Tree a   = Node a (Forest a) deriving (Show,Eq)
type Forest a = [Tree a]
-- ghc -O2 -threaded --make
-- +RTS -Nx
generate :: Graph -> Vertex -> Tree Vertex
generate g v = Node v $ map (generate g) (g V.! v)

chop :: Forest Vertex -> State IS.IntSet (Forest Vertex)
chop [] = return []
chop (Node x ts:us) = do
    visited <- contains x
    if visited then
        chop us
    else do
        include x
        x1 <- chop ts
        x2 <- chop us
        return (Node x x1:x2)

prune :: Forest Vertex -> State IS.IntSet (Forest Vertex)
prune vs = chop vs

main = do
    --edges <- V.fromList `fmap` getEdges "testdata.txt"
    edges <- V.fromList `fmap` getEdges "SCC.txt"
    let 
        -- calculate size of five largest SCC
        maxIndex = fst $ V.last edges
        gr = buildG maxIndex edges
        sccRes = scc gr
        big5 = take 5 sccRes
        big5' = map (\l -> length $ postorder l) big5
    putStrLn $ show $ big5'

contains :: Vertex -> State IS.IntSet Bool
contains v = state $ \visited -> (v `IS.member` visited, visited)

include :: Vertex -> State IS.IntSet ()
include v = state $ \visited -> ((), IS.insert v visited)


getEdges :: String -> IO [Edge]
getEdges path = do
    lines <- (map BS.words . BS.lines) `fmap` BS.readFile path
    let pairs = (map . map) (maybe (error "can't read Int") fst . BS.readInt) lines
    return [(a, b) | [a, b] <- pairs] 

vertices :: Graph -> [Vertex]
vertices gr = [1.. (V.length gr - 1)]

edges :: Graph -> [Edge]
edges g = [(u,v) | u <- vertices g, v <- g V.! u]

-- accumulate :: (a -> b -> a)  -> Vector a-> Vector (Int, b)--> Vector a
-- accumulating function f
-- initial vector (of length m)
-- vector of index/value pairs (of length n)
buildG :: Int -> Table Edge -> Graph
buildG maxIndex edges = graph' where
    graph    = V.replicate (maxIndex + 1) []
    --graph'   = V.accumulate (\existing new -> new:existing) graph edges
    -- flip f takes its (first) two arguments in the reverse order of f
    graph'   = V.accumulate (flip (:)) graph edges

mapT :: Ord a => (Vertex -> a -> b) -> Table a -> Table b
mapT = V.imap

outDegree :: Graph -> Table Int
outDegree g = mapT numEdges g
    where numEdges v es = length es

indegree :: Graph -> Table Int
indegree g = outDegree $ transposeG g

transposeG :: Graph -> Graph
transposeG g = buildG (V.length g - 1) (reverseE g)

reverseE :: Graph -> Table Edge
reverseE g = V.fromList [(w, v) | (v,w) <- edges g]

-- --------------------------------------------------------------

postorder :: Tree a -> [a]
postorder (Node a ts) = postorderF ts ++ [a]

postorderF :: Forest a -> [a]
postorderF ts = concat (map postorder ts)

postOrd :: Graph -> [Vertex]
postOrd g = postorderF (dff g)

dfs :: Graph -> [Vertex] -> Forest Vertex
dfs g vs = map (generate g) vs

dfs' :: Graph -> [Vertex] -> Forest Vertex
dfs' g vs = fst $ runState (prune d) $ IS.fromList []
    where d = dfs g vs

dff :: Graph -> Forest Vertex
dff g = dfs' g $ reverse (vertices g)

scc :: Graph -> Forest Vertex
scc g = dfs' g $ reverse $ postOrd (transposeG g)
```

Comment: Your question(s) could do with a title that reflected the content better, I think.

Comment: heap profiling might be very helpful. `prune` looks likely to have thunk leaks. And your `Table Edge` could be an unboxed vector, which should give you some additional boost.

Comment: @jberryman the issue does not seem to be memory - it seems to be steady around 75% of available capacity.  But with all 4 cores on 100% it had not finished after 10 mins

Comment: You should include some sample data. I don't know how fast you expect this to run or how fast it *can* be expected to run, but I could try to improve your code if I knew how fast it is now.

Comment: @user2407038 This code does not complete in at least 10 mins, although it does not complain about stack overflow like the official (array based) implementation.  Andras has posted a gist at https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/582808b6b5cc67bc36a2 that he claims completes on GHC 7.8.2 but overflows on 7.6.3, and which includes language elements that I have not yet learnt

Comment: It's not a good idea to use threaded run-time if your program don't use concurrent primitives. The GC mechanism is more complex and just slower.

Answer (score 1):

Some small possible improvements:

Change

```
type Edge = (Vertex, Vertex)
```

to

```
data Edge = Edge {-# UNPACK #-} !Vertex {-# UNPACK #-} !Vertex
```

to reuse the memory usage for each edge from 7 words to 3 words and to improve cache locality. Reducing memory pressure almost always also improves runtime. As @jberryman mentioned could use an unboxed vector for `Table Edge` (then you don't need the above custom data type).

```
generate :: Graph -> Vertex -> Tree Vertex
generate g v = Node v $ map (generate g) (g V.! v)
```

If you're sure that the index is in bounds, you could use the unsafe indexing function from vector instead of `.!`.

```
contains :: Vertex -> State IS.IntSet Bool
contains v = state $ \visited -> (v `IS.member` visited, visited)
```

Use a combination of `get` and `put $!` instead.

```
include :: Vertex -> State IS.IntSet ()
include v = state $ \visited -> ((), IS.insert v visited)
```

Use `modify'` instead.

You're using quite a lot of lists in your program. Linked lists aren't the most memory/cache efficient data structures. See if you can convert your code to use more vectors.