# Consecutive calls to same subroutine in fortran with significantly slower performance

Tags: performance, memory-management, fortran

**TL;DR**

My program calls a subroutine twice. The subroutine performs basically identical operations both times, but takes significantly longer to run the second time. The only difference between both calls is that data produced in the first call is used as an input in the second call. This data is stored in allocatable arrays declared in a module before the first call to the subroutine.

**Full Story**

The following shows the relevant portions of my code for the problem:

```
program Economy

!! Declarations !!

    use Modern_mod, only: Modern

    use Globals, only: Na, Ny, Ne, Vimp, Xmp, Pmp, FCp, Vimu,& ! Globals is a module containing vbles.
                     & Xmu, Pmu, FCu

    implicit none

    real(kind=nag_wp) :: param(4)

!! Execution !!

 ! First call to modern !

    param = (/1.0d0,2.0d0,3.0d0,4.0d0/)

    allocate(Vimp(Na,Ne),FCp(4,Na*Ne),Pmp(Ny,Ne),Xmp(Ny,Ne))

    call Modern(param,Vimp,FCp,Pmp,Xmp)

 ! Second call to modern !

    param = (/5.0d0,6.0d0,7.0d0,8.0d0/)

    allocate(Vimu(Na,Ne),FCu(4,Na*Ne),Pmu(Ny,Ne),Xmu(Ny,Ne))

    call Modern(param,Vimu,FCu,Pmu,Xmu)

end program Economy

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

module Modern_mod

    implicit none

    contains

    subroutine Modern(param,Vim,FCm,Pm,Xm)

    !! Declarations !!

     ! Modules !

        use Globals, only: Na, Ne, Ny

        use FindVmp_mod, only: FindVmp

        use FindVmu_mod, only: FindVmu

        implicit none

     ! Declaring other variables !

        real(kind=nag_wp), intent(in) :: param(4)                               ! param-Parameters specific to one of the modern sectors;

        real(kind=nag_wp), intent(out), allocatable :: FCm(:,:), Xm(:,:),&      ! FCm-Firm choices; Xm-Policy fun;
                                                     & Pm(:,:), Vim(:,:)        ! Pm-Price of a share; Vim-Start of period value function;

        real(kind=nag_wp), allocatable :: Vm1(:,:), Vim1(:,:), Pm1(:,:),&       ! Vm1-Vm next guess; Pm1-Next share price guess;
                                        & Vm(:,:)                               ! Vm-End of period value function; Vim1-Next Vim guess;

    !! Execution !!

     ! Allocating and initializing functions !

        allocate(Vim(Na,Ne),FCm(4,Na*Ne),Vm(Ny,Ne),Pm(Ny,Ne),Xm(Ny,Ne))
        allocate(Vim1(Na,Ne),Vm1(Ny,Ne),Pm1(Ny,Ne))

     ! Inizializing arrays !

        Vm  = ...
        Vim = ...

        ...

     ! Doing calculations !

        if(param(1) .eq. 1.0d0) then
            call FindVmp(FCm,Vim,Pm,Vm1,Pm1,Xm)         ! New value funciton guess for productive guys
        else
            call FindVmu(FCm,Vim,Pm,Vm1,Pm1,Xm)         ! New value funciton guess for unproductive guys
        end if

    end subroutine Modern

end module Modern_mod

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

module FindVmp_mod

    implicit none

    contains

        subroutine  FindVmp(FCm,Vim0,P0,Vm,P,x)

        !! Declarations !!

            use VmFp_mod, only: Calculations               ! Contains the operations computing the final values of the outputs to FindVmp

            implicit none

            real(kind=nag_wp), allocatable, intent(out) :: Vm(:,:), x(:,:), P(:,:)  ! Vm-New value function; x-Policy function; P-Share price;

            real(kind=nag_wp), intent(in) :: P0(:,:), Vim0(:,:), FCm(:,:)           ! P0-Initial share price guess; Vim-Initial guess for beginning of period value function;
                                                                                                            ! FCm-Firm choices;

        !! Execution !!

         ! Allocate matrices !

            allocate(Vm(Ny,Ne), x(Ny,Ne), P(Ny,Ne))

         ! Compute results !

            call Calculations(FCm,Vim0,P0,Vm,P,x)

        end subroutine FindVmp

end module FindVmp_mod

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

module FindVmu_mod

    implicit none

    contains

        subroutine  FindVmu(FCm,Vim0,P0,Vm,P,x) 

        !! Declarations !!

            use Globals, only: Vmp, Pmp

            use VmFu_mod, only: Calculations       ! Contains the operations computing the final values of the outputs to FindVmu

            implicit none

            real(kind=nag_wp), allocatable, intent(out) :: Vm(:,:), x(:,:), P(:,:)  ! Vm-New value function; x-Policy function; P-Share price;

            real(kind=nag_wp), intent(in) :: P0(:,:), Vim0(:,:), FCm(:,:)           ! P0-Initial share price guess; Vim-Initial guess for beginning of period value function;
                                                                                                            ! FCm-Firm choices;

        !! Execution !!

         ! Allocate matrices !

            allocate(Vm(Ny,Ne), x(Ny,Ne), P(Ny,Ne))

         ! Compute results !

            call Calculations(FCm,Vim0,P0,Vm,P,x,Vmp,Pmp)   ! Using the values of Vmp and Pmp computes in the first call to Modern

        end subroutine FindVmu

end module FindVmu_mod
```

Each run, `Modern` is fed different arrays of the same size and type (`*p` and `*u` respectively) which are declared in the module `Globals`. `Modern` similarly calls one of two very similar subroutines `FindVm?`, feeding them the corresponding arrays. `FindVmp` and `FindVmu` compute almost identical operations, only that the latter uses the values of `Vimp, Pmp` (computed in `FindVmp`) as inputs.

I've been trying to figure out why the second call to `Modern` takes up to an order of magnitude longer to complete compared to the first one.

My first guess was that maybe by allocating `Vimp` and `Pmp` at the beginning of the program, and allocating a bunch of other arrays afterwards, each reference to the former arrays might be costly because their memory addresses were far away from the arrays currently being computed in `FindVmu` (for reference, `Na = 101, Ny = 91, Ne = 9`). But then I read that `allocated` arrays are stored in the heap, and that data in the heap isn't *stacked* (no pun intended) so that this was not necessarily the origin of my problem. As a matter of fact, I've tried allocating all matrices at different points and in different orders in `Modern`, but I get roughly the same execution times.

In the same spirit, I've tried to vary how I declare some of the arrays in different subroutines (e.g. making some automatic instead of allocatable and using the compiler (ifort18) option to force them on the stack) and although I do get overall performance variations throughout the code, the relative performance of the two calls to `Modern` does not change.

Finally, I read [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462004/code-becomes-slower-as-more-boxed-arrays-are-allocated) that the more arrays you have in memory, the slower your code generally becomes. Although the explanation does make sense to me, this is the first time I experience such a significant performance loss throughout a fortran program. If this were actually the problem I'm facing, I would have expected to run into it in any number of my previous projects. Is this nonetheless a plausible cause of what is happening here?

And I'm basically out of ideas...

**Bonus Question**

While we're at it, I've found that leaving out the following lines in `Economy` surprisingly (to me) does not lead to a segfault:

```
allocate(Vimp(Na,Ne),FCp(4,Na*Ne),Pmp(Ny,Ne),Xmp(Ny,Ne))

allocate(Vimu(Na,Ne),FCu(4,Na*Ne),Pmu(Ny,Ne),Xmu(Ny,Ne))
```

In words: if I don't manually allocate the arrays declared in `Globals`, it seems like the program does so automatically once I pass them to `Modern`. Is this standard behavior or was I just lucky when I was initially not allocating them myself?

Comment: This may not be relevant to your case, but there's no point allocating `Xmp`, etc., before the call to `modern`: they're just deallocated immediately on entry to the subroutine. (This may relate to the confusion at the end: you talk about allocating arrays in `Globals`, but as far as `modern` is concerned it's seeing that as actual/dummy arguments not as those module entities.)

Comment: two things to note: (i) please supply your globals module (ii) you should try to shorten your code..

Comment: there is even more code missing. it would be helpful if you would supply a minimal working example such that we can actually run your code and see the time differences you mentioned. furthermore you could include your time measurings.

Comment: As jack says, there probably isn't enough in the question for anything but a guess: more code required, but also simplifications (to make it easier for us to follow). However, my guess is that you have some form of aliasing going on: "global" arguments being passed sometimes as arguments, sometimes being use associated (and then passed on further as arguments), and so on suggests that the design isn't clear and dataflow may be confusing. (A complete redesign may be the easiest thing for you in this case.)

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I've created a simple example regarding the last bit of my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783329/allocatable-variable-automatically-allocated-fortran). I'll work on your suggestions.