# Passing unallocated allocatable variable as an allocatable dummy argument

Tags: memory-management, fortran

In the following program, an allocatable variable `x` is passed to a subroutine `test_sub` without being allocated. The corresponding allocatable dummy variable `x_sub` is allocated in `test_sub`:

```
module test_mod

    implicit none

    contains

        subroutine test_sub(x_sub)

            implicit none
            real, allocatable :: x_sub(:)

          ! Execution !

!           return
            allocate(x_sub(1))
!           deallocate(x_sub)

        end subroutine test_sub

end module test_mod

program test

    use test_mod, only: test_sub
    implicit none
    real, allocatable :: x(:)

  ! Execution !

    print*, 'Before call to sub', allocated(x)
    call test_sub(x)
    print*, 'After call to sub', allocated(x)

end program test
```

When control is returned to the main program, `x` is allocated:

```
 Before call to sub F
 After call to sub T
```

If `test_sub` returns before allocating `x_sub`, or if `x_sub` is deallocated before returning, `x` is not allocated:

```
 Before call to sub F
 After call to sub F
```

I observe this behavior using both gfortran 4.4.7 and ifort 19.0.

My question is whether this is standard behavior. I would have expected to get a segfault when trying to pass `x` without it being allocated. I'm worried this behavior might lead to unexpected results in larger programs.

Comment: just a small side note: you should update your gfortran installation. current version is 10.2 i think.

Comment: @jack unfortunately that's up to the system administrator.

Comment: Well I would definitely ask him/her, 4.4.7 is ancient

Comment: @DrG It is not, you can install your own GCC. If you use MPI you might have a problem getting the right interconnect drivers (contact your admin) but just installing a more recent GCC is very simple. Just do it in your home directory. I did it many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `intent` declaration to control the allocation behavior of your variable inside the routine:

1. `real, allocatable, intent(inout) :: x(:)` is equivalent to your case.

   - Allocation status is not known a priori, it can be tested with `allocated(x)`;
   - Allocation status can change using `allocate`/`deallocate`
2. if `real, allocatable, intent(in) :: x(:)`, then the allocation status cannot change inside of it;

   - Can test allocation status using `allocated(x)`
   - Can not modify it
3. if `real, allocatable, intent(out) :: x(:)`, then variable x is always **initialized as non-allocated**, regardless of its former status before calling the routine, so you can *always* begin your subroutine with `allocate(x(n))`.

I believe you're using option 1) but you want 3).

Answer (score 2):

This is standard behavior. The dummy argument being `allocatable` has **no implications that the variable needs to be allocated on input or output**. It just means that the variable is allocatable such that you can treat it as an allocatable inside of that function, e.g. implicit reallocation and such.

Answer (score 1):

To find out whether it is allocated aitomatically, you should print it inside the subroutine, before executing your own `allocate`. There is no automatic allocation taking place.

It is perfectly fine to pass a non-allocated allocatable to an allocatable dummy argument. It is passed as "not allocated".